# Dc motor as torque transducer for BLDC motor

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, generator, torque, rheostat

I bought a cheap **BLDC motor** on some Chinese website and could not find its characteristics. However, I have A28-400 24V amp flow **Dc motor** with its characteristics. If I'm able to build a test rig to load the BLDC by connecting the shaft of **BLDC motor** to that of **Dc motor** and power up the **BLDC** using a commercial controller and measure current from **DC motor** (acting as a generator with a rheostat in series to vary load torque) and try to  map values of current to shaft torque of **Dc motor** using its chart.
How accurate and reliable is this method to measure torque assuming zero slippage at the coupling of the motor shafts?
And I'll be loading BLDC motor till it stalls by gradually increasing its power and decreasing resistance on the other side.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feel is you'll get it within 20% easily, 10% if you properly account for friction in the DC motor -- and without some independent way of verifying, you'll never know for sure.